# Rollbacks that undoes Example Deletion doesn't undo loss of Rep

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, rollbacks, deleted-examples

I previously asked a [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330313/cant-discard-retracted-draft) related to an example I felt was wrongly editing and then deleted because of the edits. At the time of deletion, the example had 4 upvotes. When the example was deleted, reputation was correctly removed.

> [image]

I created a rollback draft that undid the harmful changes and undeleted the question. That change was approved 2 days ago and the example was restored. However, the lost reputation was never reapplied.

> [image]

Now that example was restored, shouldn't the points also be restored?

---

*Note: I really do not care much about 10 rep points, I just have a feeling this problem is something that will come up again, possibly on a grander scale.*

Comment: If I had to venture a guess it's that *undeletion* does not schedule your account for recalculation like deletion does. Essentially your reputation is wrong until the system recalculates your account again (you haven't had one since August 11).

Comment: The rollback draft simply creates a new edit. It does not actually rollback.

Comment: @TravisJ Regardless to the editing part, it is still undeleting a previously created example.

Comment: @animuson So how do I get my account recalculated? What happened on August 11 that triggered it to recalculate then? Is this a process that is run periodically for all accounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the [most recent Docs recalc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334551/documentation-reputation-update-is-live), the reputation was re-added:

[image: +15 for upvotes]

(Unless you voted for your own example, there's bound to be another event, but I didn't go looking for it.)

The [contributor table for that example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/2314) shows how the rollback was accounted for:

```
User        Contribution Level  Start Date      End Date    End Reason
Tot Zam     Major               Jun 17 at 19:36 --          --
Rollback of a single example at Sep 5 at 21:11 to version at Jul 21 at 9:53; affected 0 contributors
```

So going forward, the only question is how soon after a deleted example gets restored that the reputation will be returned. I'm going to call this [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) for now.