# Documentation Reputation Update Is Live

Tags: discussion, documentation

#### TL;DR

Noticed your rep change?  It’s because we’re deploying an update to the rep in the Documentation Beta as was [announced a couple weeks ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333420/documentation-update-august-29th).  The biggest change: **there is now a “minor” contributor level where example upvotes give you +1 instead of +5**.

Read on for the nitty gritty of how Documentation rep now works:

#### Gaining Reputation

1. Whenever a change is approved, the author receives **+2** reputation, unless...

   - They were the last editor to all the topics modified in that change or
   - The change rolls a topic (or topic(s)) back to a previous state
2. If an answer cites a topic or example, and that answer is upvoted each contributor gets a one-time **+5**

   - A user is considered a contributor if they have ever net added 20 or more characters to the topic or example (more on contributors below)
   - This only happens once per answer-user-pair, multiple links do not stack
   - This only happens on the first upvote after a documentation link has been added, no user can gain more than +5 reputation per-answer from Documentation
3. Whenever an example is upvoted, major contributors to the example get **+5** reputation and minor contributors get **+1** reputation

   - Minor contributors are everyone who has added at least 20 characters to an example as part of a single change
   - Major contributors are the creator of the example plus everyone who has added at least 350 characters to an example

     - The 350 characters may be split across several changes, provided that each change adds at least 20 characters

#### Losing Reputation

1. If the topic(s) affected by a change are rolled back to before it was applied, the +2 from approval is removed
2. If the answer upvote is reversed, the answer is deleted, or the documentation link is edited out then the +5 from citation is removed
3. If the example upvote is reversed, the example or topic is deleted, or the contributions the user made are rolled back then the +1 or +5 is removed

   - If enough contributions are rolled back so that a user is no longer a major contributor but is still a minor contributor, the +5 is instead converted to a +1

In keeping with Q&A, if the reputation has been live for 60 or more days it is “locked in” and future deletions, removals, or rollbacks will not affect it.

#### Frequently Asked Questions

- Q: How are characters counted for minor and major contributor status?

  - A: Whitespace and formatting are removed and a per-character diff calculated.  The number of characters contributed is: <# of characters added> - <# of characters removed>
- Q:  Why can’t deletion make you a contributor?

  - A:  We found through manual evaluation of the data that while most deletes improve content, they do not improve it *as much* as the typical addition.  Accordingly the one-time +2 rep reward from their deletion being approved felt like an adequate and appropriate reward.
- Q:  Why do changes have to be 20 or more characters to affect contributor status?

  - A:  Many of the changes smaller than 20 characters are minor cleanups (spelling, punctuation, etc.) which, like deletion, feel adequately rewarded by the +2 on approval.  They do not “stack up to” contributor status because it doesn’t make sense for repeated spelling or punctuation improvements to ever equal more substantive additions.
- Q:  Why 350 characters to be a major contributor?

  - A:  This number is about 3/4ths the typical size of the initial revision of an example.  We believe adding this amount of content to existing examples is about equal to the effort that creators put in, and is thus worth the same potential reward.
- Q:  Am I still considered a contributor to a topic if my example is deleted?

  - A:  If your only contribution to a topic is through the deleted example, you will no longer be considered a contributor.  Whether that impacts your reputation depends on how old the rep gained from the example is, as detailed above.
- Q:  What happens when an example is moved?

  - A:  You may lose your contributor status to the previous topic the example was on, and may gain it on the new topic, depending on your other contributions to those topics.  Moving an example is *not* treated like a deletion, so you will not lose reputation.
- Q:  What happens if someone upvotes an example they’ve contributed to?  Or upvotes an answer that cites one of their topics?

  - A:  A user can never give themselves reputation.  Upvoting an example you’ve contributed to (or an answer that cites Documentation you’ve contributed to) may reward *other* users, but never yourself.
- Q:  What rep is subject to the daily rep cap?

  - A:  All reputation *except* the +2 from approval is subject to the daily rep cap.

#### Inspecting Contributors

There’s a a dev-y page that shows a bunch of detail about topic and example contributors.  You can find this page at `/documentation/contributors/topic/{id}` and `/documentation/contributors/example/{id}`.

[Example link](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/topic/213) for the [C Hello World topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/213/hello-world#t=20160909181038632691), and [one](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/3675) for the [Original “Hello World!” in K&R C example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/213/hello-world/3675/original-hello-world-in-kr-c#t=201609091811591704914).

[image: Contributor page]

The top two sections show all the current contributors to the topic or example, and include links to *all* the changes they have made.  These changes include those that did not affect their contributor status, and are meant to give the full context of their contributions.

The table includes everybody who has ever been considered a contributor, the dates and levels of their contributions, and if their contribution ended why it ended.

We’re exposing these details to make it easier for folks to help us find bugs and edge cases in the reputation system.

Comment: Do downvotes still have no effect other than sorting?

Comment: So the recalc has already happened?

Comment: @KevinB: They also generate an [Improvement Request](http://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-improvement-requests) if you pick a reason from the popup.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: The rules are live and Kevin is testing the recalcs. The first sentence is forward looking.

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of the Topic contributor status as opposed to the Example contributor status?

Comment: Daniel: For the citation reputation gain. Sometimes it makes more sense to link to an entire Topic rather than an individual Example.

Comment: Yay, I'm still over 500 rep. :) Glad this is out though, looks like a good start to rep changes, at the least. (I think it's great whether it changes more or not, but I know others feel differently.)

Comment: "Whenever a change is approved, the author receives +2 reputation, unless... " Does this mean deleting something as an edit that fulfills an improvement request will gain you +2 reputation?

Comment: Time to see how much of reputation I will lose.

Comment: @TylerH: Correct. The only thing that's really changed for the approved proposed change reputation are those two exceptions.

Comment: You've eliminated all incentive to update docs, barring adding a new example (unlikely due to the probability of it not being liked + effort involved), and adding substantial edits to popular examples (edits unlikely to exceed 350 char limit). +1 is not enough to compensate people from editing docs vs. asking/answering Q&A. The threshold of significant edit should be reduced significantly (50 characters or so), and incentives need to be aligned, so people pursue it vs. Q&A. I think you'll soon find people stop adding to the documentation and the quality remaining the same as it is. Not great.

Comment: This still doesn't seem to cover the problem discussed [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334085/rollbacks-that-undoes-example-deletion-doesnt-undo-loss-of-rep) where I lost the rep because my example was deleted, but never regained the rep when the example was rolled back and restored.

Comment: @the12 *"You've eliminated all incentive to update docs"* if reputation is your only incentive then you don't have to edit the docs. There will be still users who will edit it to make something better and not just for reputation.

Comment: @TotZam: Your reputation hasn't been recalculated just yet. (Not that I know if it will correct the problem you raised. We'll see.)

Comment: @the12: Our goal is to make Docs roughly equally rewarding as Q&A for similar effort. The initial system was pretty clearly too generous. If this system turns out to be unbalanced, we have several more levers to pull. Please don't assume this is the final tweak. (Also, we want to be careful about [replacing intrinsic motivation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42481/1438) with something less meaningful.)

Comment: Well, there went a lot of rep. Bummer. But seriously, thanks for working hard on addressing this; something definitely had to give.

Comment: There goes 4000 points. Deserved, I suppose. Ah well. Lets see how this new incentive structure plays out.

Comment: "Noticed your rep change?" : Yes, I'm still crying :'(

Comment: Well, I have lost a little less than 2k. Considering I had 4.5k, that's ~45%. That hurt a bit. But I have expected something similar. Will is not broken, we can still participate in doc suggestions. ;)

Comment: I feel cleansed.

Comment: @JonEricson Ok if the problem really is just that my account needs to be recalculated. If this is the case though, such a rollback then should probably automatically trigger a recalculation for all users who would be affected so that the rep points right away reappear.

Comment: @TotZam The recalculation is hitting users in batches as there are a not-insignificant number of users to go through months of history for.

Comment: I had done a few contributions to some of the topics in C++. I migrated some topics and whatnot, but I am no longer being listed as a contributor at all on the `/documentation/contributors/topic/{id}` page despite showing up on the list of contributors that have made edits on the actual documentation page itself. Why the discrepency?

Comment: @callyalater: Edits that add fewer than 20 characters are not counted as contributions for the purpose of reputation. As a result, they don't appear on the contributor report. (The report was created so that we could evaluate the new system before it changed anyone's reputation. It's such a useful and interesting report, it's become a fixture.)

Comment: @JonEricson So moving entire examples to different topics is not a major or minor edit? I'm okay with that if it is, but I had always felt that one of the benefits of documentation is in the organization. The particular topic I am referring to is the CRTP in Templates in the C++ Language category.

Comment: @JonEricson If Q&A, were equal to documentation then examples (which take similar time to make as QA) would be rewarded with +15. Problem with the current system is there's very little incentive to create new topics (+2 for a new topic vs +15 for accepted answer, both using a similar effort). Also, there is going to be 0 incentive to edit (as mentioned in my previous post), as it is very unlikely people will edit 350 chars or more (the only way to gain sufficient amount of rep). I'm just going to put my faith in you and the SO team that these things will get sorted out :)

Comment: @Rizier123 Whether you admit it or not, reputation is a huge motivation factor for documentation. Maybe there are certain users who do not care about the rep, but you cannot deny that there is decent percentage that do. If the goal of making documentation better, it is best to attract the maximum amount of users to edit the docs (while having sufficient quality control, which I do believe has been addressed via reviews), then having decent reputation alignment is important.

Comment: @the12 Well there are many users who care about reputation and many who only care about reputation and not about the quality of the docs. So attracting many users does not mean that is good for docs at all.

Comment: @Rizier123 I'd agree with you that there are users who do not care about documentation, and having great open source literature. But I do believe that the review system of SO documentation is robust enough to stomp out bad edits (requires approval of several ppl). In regards to insignificant edits, there was a line drawn in the latest update. I do believe it is necessary to cut rep overall for pointless edits, but my point was that they've taken what is a significant edit too far, and now very few people will make significant edits neccessary(doc homepage shows 0 pending edits for most topics)

Comment: @the12 I stopped making edits because of the new review system and the way it allows for all edits to be robo-reviewed by people with no rep in the tags - that was the final nail in the coffin for me. So the reason for *0 pending edits*, which I saw yesterday too, may have nothing to do with rep change.

Comment: @JGreenwell Certainly possible, as that was implemented before the rep calc (today for me atleast). Still worrying though that they are further taking away motivation from writing docs though. It would be nice to have decent documentation, rather than sort through a mish-mash of random, and inconcise, blogs/articles from Google Search.

Comment: @the12 then..... Work on making docs better? You'd like to have it, but you're unwilling to put time in it if it doesn't give you rep? If it's something i want, normally the end goal is its own reward.

Comment: Darn it, I just lost 2200 rep.  Good job.

Comment: "Noticed your rep change?" Couldnt you just keep our rep and update the new upvotes?

Comment: **Q:** Should we still disconnect Documentation rep from Q/A rep?   **A:** Hell yes.

Comment: The global message will, at least, help clarify for those folks who didn't see the Meta bulletin, and hopefully will curb the deluge of "why'd my rep go down" questions related to this.

Comment: Can we get statistics how much rep is "lost"?

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes:  It's been belabored time and time again that any changes to the rep system for Documentation would happen retroactively.

Comment: Nice touch with the global notification, but it took me 5 minutes to realize that the mob wasn't trying to send me a message (since I've already read this post, and left a comment). "*Click for details*" --> voting to close as unclear.

Comment: Better late than never I guess

Comment: The new system is fine but applying it retroactively is **not**. That's like your boss telling you "we've not only decided to decrease your pay, we're applying the decrease over the past year so now you owe us $20,000".

Comment: You can get a rough idea by viewing the diff on [the latest update here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/329740/revisions), @unor.

Comment: That beta label ain't just there to look pretty, @Hack-R.

Comment: @Shog9 It's still wrong IMHO. They should've held off on giving rep until they were ready or otherwise handled it better. We shouldn't pay for their mistakes.

Comment: I've lost 4k reputation :'( This isn't fair, I've spent at least 5 minutes to contribute to `How to use console.log()` !!

Comment: @Hack-R it's been made [horribly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/330343/5067311) [explicit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329940/can-we-please-introduce-more-reputation-limits-for-examples-on-documentation/330343#comment376865_330343) that rep is going to be recalculated. [See also](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333420/5067311).

Comment: @Hack-R Documentation is in beta, you should expect some changes.

Comment: It seems super counterproductive to think of it as 'losing' rep. That rep was never yours. If a bank accidentally gives you money, they take it back - and that's fair. If the new rules mean you get less rep, and we assume the new rules are more fair, then you were benefiting from an unfair system: to argue you should keep it is to argue for unfairness.

Comment: Jesus, I did 13 changes to the `Hello World` topic? That's a lot.

Comment: **This is the first time I am so much happy after loosing the reputations.**

Comment: @Nathaniel Ford, this is nothing like the bank example. The reputation was yours to begin with. They did a feature with the rep defined and people gained that rep. There was no mistake there. The only reason for the backlash is because of the elite high rep members getting scared that they won't be able to walk all over people and will have to share this platform with more people

Comment: Is the rep shared across sites? Like if I answer on Meta, and they get upvoted, will my StackOverflow rep also change?

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea You're incorrect, both in this being a "backlash" versus a balancing and in the notion that it is a good idea to allow - for however long - disproportionate rewards. Do you really think high rep members are worried about people earning to many fake Internet points? It's an honest attempt to cultivate - fairly! - the documentation feature.

Comment: Change the system, sure, but I disagree with going back and reverting everything already done. If the rep system worked overall, users would  naturally lose rep points through poor use of the site. Using your money anology, imagine starting a job for a certain salary and then after a few weeks your boss tells you he has to reduce your salary as he realises it's too much for your role ...fine... but then imagine he says you have to pay back some of what you already earned!

Comment: @NathanielFord high-rep members worried about people [unfairly] earning too many fake Internet points [do exist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329736/4957418)

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea If the site accidentally granted x1000 points for minor edits to JavaScript only topics, would you agree that the privileges and reputation granted was unfairly achieved? This is a normal realignment you see in any reward system. To use your analogy: your employer might grant stock along with salary. But the value of the stock is yet to be decided. Even if it was worth $100 a share on Monday, on Friday it might be only $10 a share. Remember that rep is meant to represent substantive contribution to the community, nothing else.

Comment: lost 1k rep, but honestly the amount of rep I was getting from docs was ridiculous anyway.

Comment: @DanPantry I lost 1400... But my first 1000 feel more valuable than everything else anyway :D Also I dont feel bad, but actually good

Comment: Well I am happy for you all gaining 1000 points, I think I barely got 50 for my contributions. I honestly do see the other side of the argument. But to say the site "accidentally" gave these points is inaccurate. It was designed that way, they just didn't realise what that meant until after. Kind of feels like they set the points higher to encourage high usage, only to take away the benefits once it had reached a certain size.

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea This is not the first time the rep system is modified and reapplied retroactively. If you don't wish to be affected by something likely to be reviewed in depth, don't try a beta system. That's so simple. check the comments about peoples loosing rep and comments about it being a good thing. You'll see there's a vast majority in favor of this recalc, as was the Meta posts about it before.

Comment: Just a question – if I got upvotes over doc-induced repcap, were those "recalculated"? This system sounds much better.

Comment: @Ven yes, see shog9's comment under Makoto answer

Comment: I've lost 2K, and I approve that it was much needed.

Comment: Now I have less tasks to do in Stackoverflow ... after the change, I have no longer access to the moderator tools because I lost ~1,200 rep and fell below the 10,000 boundary. Playing around with reputation points "because Docs is Beta" is not good. Would have been better if you would have given everyone testing out your beta some bonus points instead of taking away reputation. That doesn't feel good.

Comment: @NathanielFord Thats a nice idea, but unfortunately not reality. Rep is near everything on SO. What you can do is directly tied to it. Its a kind of "You made your bed and now you lay in it" situation. The ugly truth is, I would say a whole lot of people (maybe even the majority) are in it for the rep, for one reason or another.

Comment: @Matt I agree, losing rep never feels good. Just see it like "this rep should have never been given out in the first place, it was a dream all the time". Kind of imaginary rep.

Comment: *"All that we see or seem
 Is but a dream within a dream."*
**A.E. Poe.**

Comment: @Matt I have "lost" 2k+ rep and I have also lost the "access to moderator tools" privilege, but I feel that my reputation is more valuable now (I think that the reputation system was broken from a gamification point of view before this update because I think that I don't deserve all the rep gained with low effort). The question is: _Does this update makes SO better?_ For me, the answer is _yes_ because it encourages effort and better contributions, so it had to be done. PS: I will work hard(er) to regain the rep!

Comment: I agree that there was an rep inflation inflicted by the Doc beta. But that shouldn't have happened. Better give the people reputation later when the calculation algorithm is well tested than to give and take it away. Earning reputation feels better than losing it. Maybe the SO dev team can keep this in mind as "lessons learned" and avoid it in the future.

Comment: I never tried Docs because I knew that the reputation system was bad, and would cause unbalance. Now, I may consider contributing whatever tiny bits I can.

Comment: I lost a total of 2 reps :'(

Comment: @Matt, don't get your hopes up. It is not the first recalc, and I cannot allow myself to believe it will be the last.

Comment: At least it does not show as a big down in the rep graph, that would be embarrassing. Either way, the system feels way more fair to me, and I do not feel like I am getting unearned rep from upvotes

Comment: What about adding more badges?

Comment: The fact that this is so extremely complex should be a huge red flag that it will never work. Entropy is going to make this more complex than US tax system. With complexity comes loop holes and that just creates more complexity trying to address them.

Comment: @Matt See, testing the system and rep calculations is exactly what we were (and are) doing. We came up with what sounded like a reasonable default, kicked it around private beta for a bit, and then went public. At which point it turned out that the defaults were not reasonable in the slightest at Stack Overflow load. Hence the adjustment that's based on actual Docs usage we've now seen "in the wild". I appreciate that it feels rough, I really do. It was, however, unfortunately unavoidable. [status-beta] and all that.

Comment: @Adam Lear: I understand, and I suggest to add for such cases "beta reputation" which appears separately on the UI to make clear it is not real.

Comment: (I don't mind the loss of rep itself, but) the thing about the "beta rep" that bugs me the most, is that people made contributions they wouldn't have done and used privileges they wouldn't have had if they weren't going to be awarded the ridiculous amounts of rep they got, so when the retroactive recalc happened, shouldn't all those contributions and privileged actions *also* be undone?

Comment: @Amani Kilumanga: Why, are you assuming those privileges have been abused? I don't think you should assume all people are evil. However, if concerns go in that direction a user acceptance test (UAT) environment completely separate from the real web site would be the the answer.

Comment: @Matt, I don't think privileges were abused more than usual, but I do think that it is kind of hypocritical to do a retroactive rep purge and not consider a lot of other consequences. A testing environment would be the answer, but as far as I know, they already tried that with the private beta.

Comment: @Amani Kilumanga: I agree on that point. But I didn't mean a private beta, I meant a public UAT beta.

Comment: @Matt There is no beta reputation. There is a beta feature that awards Stack Overflow reputation. You are treating Q&A-sourced reputation as something set in stone as well, which isn't necessarily the case. It took several changes and recalcs over the years to get to where it's now and, while we have no plans right now to do so, it *could* change again if the need was compelling enough. All part of the process of growing Stack Overflow and learning what works better.

Comment: @Adam Lear: I know it is not there, I just made a suggestion. A suggestion is something you may consider or not, it is an idea, not more and not less.

Comment: @Matt Heh. Point taken. Consider my previous comment a "no, we're not going to do that".

Comment: I have yet to participate in documentations, so no hard feelings

Comment: Changing the rep system, OK. But this retroactive recalculation feels like...theft. Moderation is giving itself too much IMHO. Also hiding the result instead of explicitly showing the recalc rep change is really something...less than transparent. It smells.

Comment: Please never forget what rep is. Not something for the mods to play with, but the appreciation of one user for another.

Comment: The `<# of characters added> - <# of characters removed>` is not good as a major rewrite could then result in a zero sum game. Deletion is as critical as addition (when done together). I would suggest something to credit deletion when there is some addition: `<# of characters added> + min(<# of characters removed>, 0.25*<# of characters added>)`

Comment: For being a massive resource for developers, this reputation algorithm "overhaul" is uninspiring. I worked pretty hard on a few existing examples and now I've lost, albeit small, but significant privileges as a result. As a newer user I would like the chance to gain reputation since the Q&A section is pretty saturated, and this definitely discourages me from participating in the site.

Answer (score 193):

I feel like the calculation "The number of characters contributed is: <# of characters added> - <# of characters removed>" is a bit flawed.

I don't care too much about the reputation, but it's a bit disheartening to see that I'm not even a *minor* contributor after having made [this](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/1360) overhaul to a topic.

Why not just count added characters, and ignore deleted characters (rather than penalize them)? It seems strange that re-writing a paragraph counts as no contribution.

Comment: Like I said in the other comment thread, this basicly means don't bother fixing stuff, just keep adding more. Which in turn means we're in for a whole lot of cluttered through.

Comment: This should definitely change. It was okay since adding topics was important in the first place - but this is not going to make documentation a good place removing content is as important as adding new one - if not more (same goes in coding big programs)

Comment: "It seems strange that re-writing a paragraph counts as no contribution." Do it in two steps. First delete everything that is wrong. Wait until edit is approved. Then add the right information in a second edit. Never, ever mix additions and deletion in the same edit.... Okay I admit, this is just a joke. I fully agree with you. It's bad and they know it. They have been warned about it several times.

Comment: I agree with this post entirely, especially with code. If someone is doing something the long way, and you make it simpler, then you won't be considered a contributor with the new system

Comment: What are some ways not penalizing deletions would be gamed? Perhaps it would encourage rewriting code and/or paragraphs for no reason other than hitting the 350 char limit?

Comment: @JD9999 Exactly! It's as if reducing code clutter and [refactoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) was ever a bad thing... Code golf users will be pretty sad.

Comment: Haha, I love that this is the "Lines Of Code Count" problem writ in a different medium, that people have been fighting against for decades and decades.

Comment: I completely agree that the "net" method has problems. But regarding what goes wrong if you just count additions, I think the most common issues tended to be reordering edits (where simply moving a paragraph or code block is counted as a major "addition") or formatting (a big block of text or code is removed, and re-added with markup, etc.)

Comment: @Jaydles: A "Move" can be taken into consideration. Strip all formatting from a topic, then count the occurrences of `[a-z]` before, and after. Get the difference per letter, add these up, and I'd say you have a more accurate count of characters _changed_. `"I am Yoda"` > `Yoda, I am!` should return `0`. Then again, `"I am Yoda"` > `"Yo, I'm da man!"` should return just `1`, which is arguably too low.

Comment: @Jaydles Then you need to employ some more expensive calculation, eliminating appearances of any consecutive 30+ bytes (or such) which are equal in additions and deletions, after stripping whitespace, from the calculation. [Even with markup there shouldn't be that few bytes not matched by the consecutive 30+ byte sequences or the section is either very, _very_ big or markup just abused.]

Comment: Probably the "correct" approach would be using Operational Transforms to calculate minimum number of operations to transform the input into the output, and give reputation based on that. Moving a paragraph would be one operation, just like adding or removing a character. A complex rewrite would be many small operations - and commensurately rewarded.

Answer (score 118):

I think that the rep recalc is pretty widespread at present, there are many users who have had the script fix their account.

Considering how much reputation some people seemed to have amassed from minor edits, this was much needed. I like that the issue was raised, acknowledged, and addressed in a very efficient manner; and also the result seems to be fair.

With this in place, hopefully we can all move on from worrying about the Java Arrays example breaking the internet and get back to focusing on the actual reason for SO Docs: **canonical content**.

Comment: The Java Arrays example is still so huge, there is danger that when it collapses, people will get stuck under the debris... (But at least probably less people will try and poke it...)

Comment: @ppeterka - I agree it isn't fully fixed, but there are more features in the pipeline that should be able to assist with that type of example. In addition, hopefully the structure that comes out in the next few waves will prevent that type of all encompassing content being created. Conversely, just to consider, perhaps the Java Arrays example is what users actually want out of Docs? Food for thought.

Comment: I hope Docs will not turn out to embrace such examples - or at least retains a way to have to-the-point, more code-less talk examples. I'm fully in for that cheatsheet approach - but there are numerous already existing resources and platforms available for the walls of text teaching and preaching kind of stuff. Do we need another one? OTOH I could imagine a site structured in the Docs way, but gathering the links of multiple similar tutorials into one place, each competing with the others by voting - a love child of Reddit and Docs. (Ain't gonna happen as it is 3rd party content...)

Comment: `there are more features in the pipeline that should be able to assist with that type of example` - now that is something [I'm eagerly waiting for](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333476/the-dreaded-java-arrays-topic-rate-my-draft)...

Comment: I'm a little worried about how the new incentive system encourages making examples even larger and doesn't reward housekeeping at all. There will be nothing canonical about these, just lots of pitfighting over edits.

Comment: @Magisch as I understand it, you receive the +2 for an approved edit. It just limits the +5 that you were getting for every upvote on the example, which makes total sense

Comment: @Lamak Yeah. Assume that you can choose by artificially making an example longer and getting hundreds of rep or do the right thing and get maybe 2. That sets a terrible incentive. But I guess thats just one of these things that need to be seen in live to be changed

Comment: @Magisch What do you mean? You even get +2 reputation for [deleting stuff](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334551/documentation-reputation-update-is-live#comment395281_334551)!

Comment: @TylerH 2 rep for an edit is so insignificant as to be meaningless considering we're talking hundreds for edits that make the example longer artificially. If it was 20 or 30, maybe, but thats still a big maybe.

Comment: @Magisch every type of incentive can be gamed, doesn't mean that this change isn't the right one

Comment: @Lamak The right change should reward proper editing, that is in most cases removing just as much from any given example as adding. Making added characters a metric was fundamentally wrong imo. I'd venture so far as to say for nearly all examples most edits adding lots of text are actively harmful. Now these are the only thing the system rewards anymore.

Comment: @Magisch and it **is** rewarding them. Do you think it would be ok to edit minor things on an answer or a question in SO and get rep for every upvote there?. I still feel dirty for receiving rep for some upvotes on an example I edited lightly

Comment: In essence that means we'll be seeing lots and lots of fluff added to examples already way too big which will mean more browser clutter, less performance, and less overall usability. In the current system, pending a quick change for the opposite direction, docs is poised to die the death of a thousand cuts.

Comment: @Lamak Would you feel okay for recieving rep from every upvote for an answer where you just re-worded the grammar in such a way as to elongate the sentences significantly for no gain? No? Thats significantly worse, and thats what will happen.

Comment: @Magisch Those changes need to be approved, and as always, we need to trust the users that can approve them to spot this kind of things. I would ask you to lend me that magic crystal ball where you are watching this things happening though, since you are so certain as to what's coming

Comment: "*focusing on the actual reason for SO Docs: canonical content.*" Isn't the actual reason for docs **missing** content?

Comment: "canonical" is overused and misused (to mean... decent? comprehensive?) It's pretty unlikely SO Docs will ever be *canon* for a great many topics; @null is correct, the problems being targeted here are more in the missing / incomplete / incomprehensible docs camp.

Comment: @Shog9: "*the problems being targeted here are more in the missing / incomplete / incomprehensible docs camp*" And yet, there's no reason to expect the system to accomplish that. Things with dysfunctional documentation get that way usually because it's not widely known and/or used. So how will Docs.SO change that?

Comment: Simply lowering the bar to changes may go a long way there, @Nicol. Hard to tell if that'll work at this point; my impression is that it took 6 to 9 months before questions on SO exhausted the easy stuff and started really getting into the juicy edge-cases.

Comment: Do you guys have a *plan*? @Shog9♦ What if "*Simply lowering the bar to changes*" does not go a long way? I sometimes ask questions on SO because of missing documentation. I rarely get good answers to those if any at all. I lost faith in SO docs not because of a broken rep system but because [it doesn't work as advertised](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331946/4347580). Why would somebody go to docs in "*6 to 9 months*" to write down what would be necessary to answer a question that exists today? The bar for answering a question is already on the ground, how could docs have a lower one?

Comment: " canonical content." Canonical, example centric content, you do not find elsewhere already in sufficient quality. And as a wish: well organized canonical, example centric content which doesn't exist elsewhere.

Comment: @TylerH You get +2 rep for any approved edit. In other words you get +2 rep for adding stuff as well, so there is no incentive to reduce clutter instead of adding fluff.

Comment: Please understand, @null: I wasn't trying to be glib with that "6-9 months" comment. The initial questions on SO - and on pretty much every new platform added to SO since - tended toward the big, popular problems that everyone encounters at some point and half of everyone already knows the answer to. You could find most of the same answers on existing forums, existing Q&A sites, in the official docs... It took months to gather that *long tail* of errata that few people care about but *in aggregate* actually solves a big chunk of folks' daily problems.

Answer (score 29):

The reputation system is now more balanced. The biggest flaw I still see is the length based dependence of the reputation gained. This will incentivize bloat, i.e. overly verbose contributions with a low density of information.

This problem will aggravate over time, when it becomes less about building up content but more about improving quality of existing content.

This may seriously impede the success of Documentation!

Problem: I find it difficult to come up with anything better. Rating edits seems to be overkill.

Best alternative I have: Blame the contribution line by line to contributors, then distribute reputation for upvotes based on percentage of lines one contributed to, normalize by total number of contributions to single lines. This assumes that every line is equally important, but at least it doesn't scale with the length.

Comment: rating edits in edit approval queue?

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC Yes, why not. If you already look at the edit and decide if it's worthy to stay you could as well classify it along the way. Not sure though that three to five ratings would be enough to get statistical accuracy. But it could work.

Comment: a major two char edit should have more than a spelling fix.

Comment: Gonna flesh this out as a feature request, I'll need help though.

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC I like the idea. If you propose it I will definitely support it. You could for example show a display of a screenshot of the current Documentation review queue, then one how you imagine it to be so that a classification (cosmetic, minor, major) is possible and then propose that we test this system against their system, then manually judge who is better and then keep the better system. It's worth a try.

Comment: willing to write it together? ;)

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC I can do it tomorrow if you haven't done it by then. ;)

Comment: google docs and just use the collab feature?

Comment: Similar suggestion is [documentation-shares-the-work-make-the-rewards-shared-not-multiplicative](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329506/documentation-shares-the-work-make-the-rewards-shared-not-multiplicative)

Answer (score 21):

It would have been nice to keep track of how much reputation was lost for an individual user, since we do have wildly varying reports of how much reputation was lost.  It wouldn't be something that'd be public since reputation loss is *generally* private, but it would have been a nice-to-have.

All in all, I do feel like the major concerns about how much rep Documentation is contributing to the ecosystem at large can mostly be soothed, since it's not a whole lot anymore.

Comment: Figure on [> 50% of all reputation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/329740/revisions) being eliminated today, skewed heavily toward the top rep-earners.

Comment: @Shog9: Suppose one day a user got 50 points from documentation edits, and 150 points from up-votes on Q&A, and also got 6 answer up-votes that generated no benefit because the 200 cap limit was reached. Further, suppose that the documentation recalc eliminates 40 of the 50 documentation points. Does the user still get credit for the answer up-votes that would've counted had the doc points not been granted? For the hypothetical user, would the net score not change, even though the contribution from doc edits decreases? (I rather assume that the answer is "Yes", but reassurance would be nice.)

Comment: Yes, @jonathan. Recalc means the world is rewritten under the new rules - the rep for that day is as it would be if the cap had been reached slightly later due to the answer votes.

Answer (score 13):

> Q: Why 350 characters to be a major contributor? A: This number is
>   about 3/4ths the typical size of the initial revision of an example.
>   We believe adding this amount of content to existing examples is about
>   equal to the effort that creators put in, and is thus worth the same
>   potential reward.

This doesn't solve much when the initial revision was smaller than 350 characters and then it was expanded into a much larger example. So while in most cases the reward for the creator is justified, there are certain scenarios where it isn't.

For example: [Inner Join - SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/3270/) (initially 152), [Insert Into - SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/3748/) (initially 65), [Return multiple values using std::tuple - C++](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/1601/) (initially 115), and [Get and invoke method Reflection - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/68/) (initially 251).

Disclaimer: I expanded the Insert Into example.

Answer (score 4):

Tangentially related to this, but I received an email notification about this post, saying "the following item was added to your Stack Exchange global inbox"...  I'm on Android, and have the SE app installed.  Clicking the link in the email did *not* launch anything, neither the app or the browser.

I manually opened the SE app, and either couldn't find any sort of "inbox" functionality, or there was no notification of this post.   I swiped from the right to the left (or clicked on the number icon in the upper left corner) and say what appear to be older notifications, but no mention of this post.

Should I have expected this to all work within the Android app?

Comment: Ask another question for this.

Answer (score 2):

There are minor changes that contribute substantially to a topic. I think it should be up to the reviewers to see if it's a minor edit, like a spelling correction, or a substantial edit worth reputation points.

The 20 character addition limit will just cause people to game it, rewriting sentences to be slightly longer, etc. [Here's an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/64227) I made that is really small (-2 +2 characters), but it has a fairly big impact.

[Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/80880) of a change big enough that the original author shouldn't get reputation points any more, but because the diff tool wants to find similarities, it passes the 20 character limit just by me using the same function name. The previous version didn't even compile.

Comment: _"I think it should be up to the reviewers to see if it's a minor edit"_ I disagree. Reviewers get it wrong, too often.

Comment: The algorithm also gets it wrong too often, but which one is better? Some combination?

Comment: I don't think that your first link has a big impact, you just renamed some a variable

Comment: @SZenC I didn't rename a variable. I changed the example to use the middle variable instead of the left-most one, to illustrate that there are no pointer relations between them in either direction, avoiding a possible misunderstanding. See the edit comment at the top.

Comment: @FilipHaglund: I'd hardly call that a "big impact", especially since the significance isn't explained in the example.

Comment: @Cerbrus `In this case, a, b, and c, are all independent -- changing one will not change the others` isn't enough?

Comment: The significance of the _edit_.

Comment: Perhaps the system will get to automatically mark edits as major, but those marked minor (or too small to be marked at all) will be decided by a reviewer vote. This way people can't just make everything a major edit, and the fine line between no significance or minor is left to the discretion of the reviewers.

Comment: @Cerbrus The diff and characters added metric to judge worthiness of a edit is so inaccurate as to be meaningless entirely. Even if reviewers got the classification wrong 90% of the time, it'd still be better then the current system.

Comment: @Magisch: I agree that the current system is <redacted>. Still, I trust reviewers even less.

Answer (score 2):

The new reputation points system is better than the previous.

However, you should consider something to improve the **remarks/syntax/parameters sections**.
In most of the cases these sections are empty.

Comment: Ok, so you deleted your other answer but this one seems to end on a partial word, and not be completely formatted.

Comment: definitely. did not expect so much from a zero upvote answer

Answer (score -4):

I feel like Documentation has the potential to become something really powerful and useful but I'm afraid that this will reduce contributors to it, although I agree that the reputation was indeed too much and that would probably lead to low quality posts on the long run.

Maybe a good way to incentivate people to contribute more to Documentation may be add more badges as rewards for being constant. I'm not sure if this would be a good idea though because people may start to exploit it like for reviews.

I am trying to participate anytime I have the opportunity myself but personally I don't feel comfortable yet on how the browsing works. I guess I'll get used to it eventually.