# No reputation for topic creation in documentation. Removed in Documentation Reputation Update

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, documentation

I have created few topics in documentation and awarded +2 reputation for each topic. Now that all are removed during Documentation Reputation Update.

in this [documentation update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334551/documentation-reputation-update-is-live), it is mentioned gaining reputation is only for edit.

Is it correct?. No reputation for topic creation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a bug in the *recalc* code for Documentation rep, which caused changes that created a topic to be treated as if they were repeated edits by the same user.

TL;DR - [`NULL` comparison strikes again](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/636/filter-results-using-where-and-having/2235/where-clause-with-null-not-null-values#t=20160927173905984468)

[image]

New creations were unaffected, so not everybody who created a new topic was affected.

Recalcs for affected users are queued up, so that rep should be awarded in the next couple of hours.

Answer (score 3):

On [your reputation report](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6624680/ponnarasu?tab=reputation), you can see three entries labeled "doc change" worth +2 each:

- Sept. 1: [Converting from MyISAM to InnoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/s/pc/91617?repUserId=6624680)
- Sept. 2: [Drop table](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/s/pc/92040?repUserId=6624680)
- Sept. 11: [Transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/s/pc/93830?repUserId=6624680)

You do have 5 items on your [Documentation contributions report](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6624680/ponnarasu?tab=documentation&sort=contributions). I do not believe either of the [new exceptions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334551/documentation-reputation-update-is-live) (last editor or rollback) apply to one the missing edits because there doesn't seem to be any reptuation gain at all:

- Sept. 2: [Temporary Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/91935)

The other missing edit did not award reputation for the initial edit:

- Sept. 3: [Transation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/92270)

There was [another contributor](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/topic/5771), but he seems to have submitted his edits just after approving yours.

So I'll need to check with a dev to see if there's something I missed or if this is a bug.

Comment: Thanks for considering my question. If initial edit did not award any reputation, then nothing missed for me. `Temporary Tables` and `Transaction` was initial edit only

Comment: @Ponnarasu: Those edits _should_ have been awarded with +2. So that's why I think there might be a bug.