# Major contributor status granted for creating a Topic?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, documentation

All of my edits on [this contributor breakdown](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/topic/5541) show that I was simply shuffling examples:

[image]

And yet I have "Major" contributor status in the table below it. Is this just because I created the Topic? I don't see it covered in [the rep update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334551/documentation-reputation-update-is-live?cb=1).

Not a big deal, but I'm curious. I'm guessing the only benefit from that status comes if people link from Q&A to the topic.

Comment: Not sure if this should be tagged with "support" or what...

Comment: I also moved a couple of examples from a very broad topic to a newly created topic and on that new topic I am a major contributor. It doesn't seem right (I have no contribution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main effect of contributor status for a *Topic* is that you will be able to earn citation rep. Considering there's value in reorganizing topics and there's no other way to reward people who do that beyond the +2 for approved changes, we are leaning to keeping the *status quo*. (This was not entirely intentional; it was just how the code worked out.)

However, if other consequences turn up, we're open to other approaches.