# Why is a user whose contribution I reverted still considered a contributor?

Tags: support, documentation

[This example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/487/how-to-return-several-values-from-a-function/3621/using-a-function-object-consumer#t=201609151630243796949) in the C++ documentation has [4 revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/revisions/487?exampleId=3621).

My revision (the 3rd one) completely reverted the 2nd edit, but added other minor details onto the original revision. The 4th revision adds a bunch more info.

But if I look at the [contributor list](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/3621), the user whose edit I completely reverted is a Minor Contributor. I am not a Contributor of any kind. Why is this the case? Moreover, the user in question is listed as having modified the section for 125 characters, but [that edit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/22586) is only 92? This all seems inconsistent to me.

Comment: A lot of this could be explained by edits occurring within the 5 minute ninja window.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's always the ninjas' faults.

Comment: You are not thinking like a programmer here.  You did not "completely revert" the edit, words like template, void, int, etc survived.  Looks minor to me :)

Answer (score 20):

In order to revert an edit, you gotta use the rollback mechanism:

[image: Rollback mechanism]

Admittedly, this is a bit obscure. First, you can't have an outstanding draft on the topic. Then, when you are on the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/revisions/487?exampleId=3621), you gotta pick the View Topic button:

[image: View Topic]

Then you need to scroll down to the example you want to rollback, create the draft and submit it.

Unless I'm missing something obvious, rolling back an edit could be easier and more intuitive.

Comment: That probably would've helped earlier. But for now - what's with the Contributor statuses of me and the other guy?

Comment: @Barry: You can find the details in [this announcement](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334551/1438). Essentially, the contribution you manually reverted stays because the algorithm only removes contributions on rollback and you don't get contributor status for adding fewer than 20 characters. We don't have a good solution for rolling back a change that was improved upon, it's not easy to correct the problem just yet. :-(

Comment: I don't understand the math. My edit was +46/-39 and the other guy's was +43/-49. I could understand both of us being contributors, and I could understand neither of us being contributors...