# Towards understanding how linking to a doc example awards you

Tags: discussion, support, documentation, answers, reputation

In my relatively old [Why does this program print “forked!” 4 times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716255/why-does-this-program-print-forked-4-times/26716300#26716300), I updated my answer, to link to a documentation example, where two others and I are listed in the revisions.

From that point, it seems that I got an upvote in the answer, which triggered a +10 notification. I would expect something like a +15 (or maybe something less with the new changes). What am I missing here?

---

Note: the example is linked in sub tags.

---

Edit:

Note that in [Active tasks is a negative number in Spark UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38964007/active-tasks-is-a-negative-number-in-spark-ui), I did update the answer with an example, and when I got an upvote, I got awarded +15.

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with it being in a subscript.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to edit right now @NathanOliver! ;)

Comment: Is it possible you already got the one-time +5 documentation bonus from that answer?  Like ages ago and it's already been accounted for during the reputation recalc a few days ago?

Comment: @ryanyuyu check my edit! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually already earned the [*one-time* bonus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334551/documentation-reputation-update-is-live/) from your documentation piece being cited in an upvoted answer.  Checking the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26716300/timeline), your answer got its first  upvote after the documentation link edit on August 12.  Comparing this with your [reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2411320/gsamaras?tab=reputation&sort=time&page=2):

> [image: Reputation history]

You probably didn't notice because it was retroactively awarded to you as part of the recent documentation-related reputation recalculation.

Comment: Dern it, you beat me to it! :)

Comment: haha.  Seems to happen often.  I love the post timelines.  They're so useful.

Comment: So now @ryanyuyu, let's say that you upvote my answer, I will get a +15, or it will be broken down again?

Comment: @gsamaras Unless you linked to another doc that you contributed to before the vote, you would only get +10. The extra +5 is a _one time per answer_ bonus, and you don't have to be the one to link it. In fact, if that had not been an example that you had contributed to, you wouldn't have gotten the +5 for the citation to begin with. You get the +5 once per answer that links the example, the first time that answer is upvoted.

Comment: Ah I see @Kendra, I will eagerly wait for the next upvote in my answer to see what you said, thanks! :)