# Reputation count bug

Tags: support, reputation

I just answered a question and, before the 10 min I saw a `+15` poping on top of my screen. Like if my answer was accepted but the tick was not displayed and stackoverflow.com/reputation showed:

```
-- 2016-10-18 rep +25   = 17045     
 1  40086685 (15)
 2  40124941 (10)
 2  40124941 (10)
 2  40131934 (10)
 2  40131934 (10)
-- 2016-10-19 rep +55   = 17100     
 2  19729433 (10)
 2  40158492 (10)
 40158492 (5) <-- wat?
 2  40158492 (10)
-- 2016-10-20 rep +35   = 17135
```

Is this coming from the documentation? Or anywhere else?

Comment: 10 (answer upvote) + 5 (Documentation topic cited)

Comment: Wut? I'll get 5 rep from every topic I cited? Also, I miss the voteTypeID

Comment: Huh, I didn't notice you linked to it yourself. I don't know then, maybe it's normal.

Comment: Your rep screen shows you got a upvote and a docs cite rep.  You do not get rep from  citing docs until you get an upvote.  This includes editing a doc cite into an already upvoted answer.

Comment: And you still get the bonus, even if it's your own edit that adds the citation link.

Answer (score 2):

The extra +5 comes from your contribution to [backtracking](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/977/backtracking/3180/why-backtracking-can-be-a-trap#t=201610201559558646731) being cited in this [answer that was upvoted with your citation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40158435/multiple-consecutive-in-expression-lead-to-slow-matching/40158492#40158492):

> [image: Reputation history]

The [current reputation scheme for documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334551/documentation-reputation-update-is-live):

> If an answer cites a topic or example, and that answer is upvoted each contributor gets a one-time +5 ...
>
> - This only happens on the first upvote after a documentation link has been added, no user can gain more than +5 reputation per-answer from Documentation

You still get the documentation citation bonus the first time your contribution is cited in an answer, even if you are the one citing it.  All that matters is that the answer later gets an upvote while your Documentation citation is there.  And then Documentation (not Q&A) awards you 5 reputation for your contributions.