# No reputation gain for approved edits in "R Language"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, documentation, reputation

Even though my contributions are approved, no  reputation is awarded for R Language Documentation. I receive +2 reputation for other topics such as Latex, but not for R Language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Since September 14](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334551/documentation-reputation-update-is-live), you only get the +2 reputation for an approved change if you are not the last person listed as the editor for every section of the edit and the change is not a rollback of a previous edit.

Looking at the [revision history there](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/revisions/1686), you've been continuously editing the topic by yourself. Only select edits in that long string there will have given you the +2 reputation.