# Is it acceptable to paste documentation from a framework in to SO Documentation for that topic

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-topics

An example is the MS BotFramework.

The documentation on their site is pretty extensive. Is it acceptable to paste that information directly into a SO Documentation topic? Or does it all have to be user written?

Comment: A major issue I see with that is the license of the information provided by Microsoft. Could you even legally use that text as-is?

Comment: @SplittyDev I dont see why not, if you link back to their site. It is not like this is being used for profit or gain.

Comment: Ah yeah I guess that would be okay. Other than that, I don't see a problem with doing this. I've seen a lot of copy-pasted stuff on SO Docs, though that was mostly only one paragraph and not the whole example. I'm not too experienced though, so better get a third opinion.

Comment: "I dont see why not, if you link back to their site. It is not like this is being used for profit or gain" -- On the contrary, I don't see why it would be okay without a license that explicitly allowed it. @SplittyDev 's original objection should be taken seriously. (Besides that, duplicating official documentation is a questionable move even from a purely editorial point of view.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Please don't

It's fine to quote bits of official documentation as long as you [properly cite it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). But generally we don't want long sections of official documentation copied into SO Documentation. We're trying to do something a little different. The goal is for our content to be:

- Crowd-sourced,
- Community-vetted, and
- Example-driven.

Copying official documentation (besides being a little underhanded), fails to achieve those goals as a rule. We want you to use your experience to write the sort of content you'd find useful when you forget, say, how to use [lookahead and lookbehind regexen](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/639/lookahead-and-lookbehind/2089/basics#t=201702100649239285039). It's not intended to be complete (unless completeness is critical) or a tutorial (unless the student is fairly bright). Instead focus on the humble task of being a useful answer to questions that would be closed as "too broad" on the Q&A side.

In addition, copying and pasting will give you an unfair advantage in terms of [reputation gain](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334551/documentation-reputation-update-is-live) until someone notices and rolls back your changes.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I thought but wanted to check.