# My Documentation edit was approved, but my reputation didn't increase

Tags: support, documentation

I have edited a documentation [Spring boot + Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/spring-boot/6203/spring-boot-spring-data-jpa#t=201707311139503886632). Then community has approved my edit.

I have seen that, my edit is live now, but I haven't got any reputation(+2) for that.

**N.B**: I have got +2 in past edit for the same post. Shouldn't Doc edit be like usual "Question Edit"?

Comment: IIRC you do not get rep for a minor edit and I believe you also only get rep for the first edit.

Comment: @NathanOliver, yes, I have got rep. for my first edit. But, In SO question/answer, I have got multiple +2 for the same question/answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The current reputation rules for Documentation are…documented [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334551/documentation-reputation-update-is-live). Regarding edits, it says:

> #### Gaining Reputation
>
> 1. Whenever a change is approved, the author receives **+2** reputation, unless...
>
>    - They were the last editor to all the topics modified in that change or
>    - The change rolls a topic (or topic(s)) back to a previous state

The first "unless" condition applies here. You edited that example [three hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/151587?filter-tags=spring-boot), and then again [one hour ago](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/151637?filter-tags=spring-boot). You would have gotten +2 reputation for the first edit, but not for the second. That was totally fair in this case, because the second edit just fixes a mistake that you missed the first time. You really should have done both things at the same time, in a single edit.